# mouseMoved not called when over the View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsresponder

I have subclass of NSView which implements mouseMoved.

However when I move my mouse over the view the mouseMoved never gets called. Why?

I am on OS X Lion.

Thanks,
Vance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even with -setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:, your view will only get -mouseMoved: when it is the first responder. If you want to receive mouse moved events when your view isn't first responder, give NSTrackingArea a look.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling mouseMoved events on the window containing the view via the NSWindow class's setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents: method

Comment: I do try to set "[pullDownWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];" on the NSWindow instance the view is part of but still nothing. Is there something else?

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem by putting this hack in the CCDirectorMac:
after:

```
 [fullScreenWindow_ makeMainWindow];
 [fullScreenWindow_ makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

set acceptMouseMovedEvents to yes:

```
 [fullScreenWindow_ setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
```